# como elimino el espacio en th de una tabla?

Tags: css, html5, css3

tengo una tabla diseñana en css y llenada con php y mysql,mi problema es que hay un espacio que nose como eliminarlo,gracias

codigo de tabla y estilo

```
    <div id="tabla_paciente" style="overflow-x:auto;">
     <table id="pacientes">
        <tr>   

                <th>CONDICION DE INGRESO</th>
                <th>N. DE CASO</th>
                <th>N. HISTORIA</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>NOMBRE</th>
                <th>FASE</th>
                <th>ASISTENCIA</th>
                <th>FALTAS</th>
                <th>TRATAMIENTO</th>
                <th>MANTENIMIENTO</th>
       </tr>
    <?php 

     while ($row = $resultado_personas->fetch_array())

      {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['condiingreso']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['nro_caso']; ?></td>     
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['cod_historia']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['dni']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['apellidopaterno']." ".$row['apmaterno']." ".$row['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['fase']; ?></td>
            <td align="center">50</td>
            <td align="center">50</td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['cntidad']; ?></td>
            <td align="center">
            <a href="editarpaciente.php?cod_det_trata=<?php echo $row['codigodet']; ?>" ><img id="imgeditar" src="../img/editar.png" width="10%" height="15%"></a>
            <a href="elininarpaciente.php?cod_det_trata="<?php echo $row['codigodet']; ?>><img id="imgeditar" src="../img/eliminar.png" width="10%" height="15%"><

/a>

    </tr>
    <?php
    } 
     ?>


  </table>

  </div>
```

ESTILO

```
table {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

IMAGEN DONDE APARECE LOS ESPACIOS 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es porque la tabla tiene width 100%, solo tienes que quitar está propiedad de CSS o darle un ancho en % a las distintas columnas para repartir si quieres que la tabla ocupe todo el ancho. Además te falta cerrar el último td, solo por corrección de código.

Comment: <th style="width: 200px;">MANTENIMIENTO</th> juega con esa propiedad

Answer (score 0):

Esos espacios son porque tienes la tabla al 100%

```
   table {
      margin-top: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
}
```

puedes usar

```
th:nth-child(-n+9){
    width: 70%;
}
```

así aumentas el tamaño de las demás columnas, cambia el 70% al que necesites

Answer (score 0):

Tu tabla está al 100% de su contenedor (la pantalla) pero las columnas no están definidas, por lo tanto simplemente se ajustan al contenido. Como la prioridad es el texto, todo el espacio que sobra se lo da a la columna con las imágenes.

Lo que yo te recomiendo es que a cada columna le asignes su propio `width`, pero además considera usar las etiquetas [`thead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) y [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) (también existe [`tfoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot)) [para hacer tu web *semántica*](http://www.w3c.es/Divulgacion/GuiasBreves/WebSemantica):

```
<table id="pacientes">
    <thead>
        <tr>   
            <th style="width:10%">CONDICION DE INGRESO</th>
            <th style="width:10%">N. DE CASO</th>
            <th style="width:10%">N. HISTORIA</th>
            <th style="width:14%">DNI</th>
            <th style="width:15%">NOMBRE</th>
            <th style="width:10%">FASE</th>
            <th style="width:5%">ASISTENCIA</th>
            <th style="width:5%">FALTAS</th>
            <th style="width:15%">TRATAMIENTO</th>
            <th style="width:6%">MANTENIMIENTO</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 

 while ($row = $resultado_personas->fetch_array())

  {

    ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['condiingreso']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['nro_caso']; ?></td>     
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['cod_historia']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['dni']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['apellidopaterno']." ".$row['apmaterno']." ".$row['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['fase']; ?></td>
            <td align="center">50</td>
            <td align="center">50</td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['cntidad']; ?></td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="editarpaciente.php?cod_det_trata=<?php echo $row['codigodet']; ?>" ><img id="imgeditar" src="../img/editar.png" width="10%" height="15%"></a>
                <a href="elininarpaciente.php?cod_det_trata="<?php echo $row['codigodet']; ?>><img id="imgeditar" src="../img/eliminar.png" width="10%" height="15%"></a>
            </td><!-- Además te faltaba cerrar esto -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo esto muy sencillo por si quieres aplicarlo.

Es sólo un poco de CSS, nada más, y tu tabla queda totalmente limpia. Si quieres, puedes alcanzarla por un nombre de clase y aplicarle esas reglas... o lo que quieras.

Espero te sirva.

```css
/* CSS */

td, th{
    border:1px solid #000;
}

tr td:last-child{
    width:1%;
}
```

```html
<!-- * HTML */ -->

     <table id="pacientes">
        <tr>   

                <th>CONDICION DE INGRESO</th>
                <th>N. DE CASO</th>
                <th>N. HISTORIA</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>NOMBRE</th>
                <th>FASE</th>
                <th>ASISTENCIA</th>
                <th>FALTAS</th>
                <th>TRATAMIENTO</th>
                <th>MANTENIMIENTO</th>
       </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center">condiingreso</td>
            <td align="center">nro_caso</td>     
            <td align="center">cod_historia</td>
            <td align="center">dni</td>
            <td align="center">apellidopaterno.apmaterno.nombre</td>
            <td align="center">fase</td>
            <td align="center">50</td>
            <td align="center">50</td>
            <td align="center">cntidad</td>
            <td align="center">
            <a href="editarpaciente.php?cod_det_trata=<?php echo $row['codigodet']; ?>" ><img id="imgeditar" src="../img/editar.png" width="10%" height="15%" /></a>
            <a href="elininarpaciente.php?cod_det_trata="><img id="imgeditar" src="../img/eliminar.png" width="10%" height="15%"></a>
            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```